# How to check if a value exist in table column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the scenario and table structure:

[image]

For a given token there can be 3 values assigned

- Cash
- Cheque
- Draft

I was trying out a query which can fetch me the `Token_Id` of records for which there is no Draft value in `Field_Value` column.
From the above image i need the value `1`. As it is the only records which has no `draft` values.

If i am firing the below query is it correct.

```
select * from cash_memo where field_value not in ('Cash')
```

Please guide.

Comment: *Below is the scenario and table structure:* my proxy prevents me from seeing images. Don't post table structures as image by the way, but as text, so we can copy/paste and do some tests

Comment: Token_Id Field_Value
1 Cash
2 Draft
2 Cheque
3 Cash
3 Cheque
3 Draft
4 Cheque
4 Draft

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55158694/edit) please

Comment: Sample data as formatted text is a good start, but don't forget the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way:

```
select token_id
from yourTable
group by token_id
having count (case when field_value = 'Draft' then 1 end) = 0
```

Here I count the rows with `field_value = 'Draft'` and only get the `token_id` for which this count gives 0.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `NOT EXISTS` should do it:

```
SELECT * -- or DISTINCT token_id
FROM cash_memo
WHERE field_value <> 'draft'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cash_memo AS x
    WHERE token_id = cash_memo.token_id
    AND field_value = 'draft'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `not in`

```
select c.* from cash_memo c
    where  token_id not in (  select token_id 
                             from cash_memo 
                             where field_value = 'Draft')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE cash_memo ( token_id, field_value ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Cash'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Draft'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Cheque' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Cash'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Draft'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Cheque' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Draft'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Cheque' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Cash'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Cheque' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**: If you want all the columns for the rows where there is no `'Draft'` value for that `token_id` then you can use an analytic function:

```
SELECT token_id,
       field_value
FROM   (
  SELECT token_id,
         field_value,
         COUNT( CASE field_value WHEN 'Draft' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY token_id )
           AS numDraft
  FROM   cash_memo c
)
WHERE numDraft = 0;
```

**Output**:

```
TOKEN_ID | FIELD_VALUE
-------: | :----------
       1 | Cash       
       5 | Cash       
       5 | Cheque
```

**Query 2**: If you just want a list of the `token_id` which have no `'Draft'` values:

```
SELECT token_id
FROM   cash_memo
GROUP BY token_id
HAVING ( COUNT( CASE field_value WHEN 'Draft' THEN 1 END ) = 0 );
```

**Output**:

```
| TOKEN_ID |
| -------: |
|        1 |
|        5 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=39512d873e6df368b965e10496eb52dc)*

Answer (score -1):

This is simple using **FIND_IN_SET** , you can try this

```
SELECT token_id FROM yourTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('{Draft}', field_value )
```

Here search key in {}

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle and there is no `FIND_IN_SET` function in Oracle.

Comment: OMG, Am sorry, I just thought MYSQL only... No issues instead of FIND_IN_SET you can use 'INSTR' in Oracle. Please see the reference https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm .